# Biggest possible sum of multiples

Tags: c++, arrays, sum, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

How would you solve this?

> You have 2 arrays, each with n numbers, n <= 500.  You can choose one number from
>   the first three in first array and multiple it with first number in
>   second array. Continue doing this until every number is used. Write
>   the biggest possible sum of these multiples.

For example:

```
n = 4;
first array contains : 16 6 2 10
second array contains : 3 8 12 9
Output : 336
```

> For first number from second array - 3 - you can choose from 16,6 and
>   2. Best option is to choose 2. Sum is now 3 * 2 = 6;
>    For second number from second array - 8 - you can choose from 16,6,10 (number 2 is
>   already used). Best option is to choose 6. Add 8 * 6 to sum, so sum is
>   now 54.
>   For third number from second array - 12 you can choose from
>   16,10 (number 2 and 6 are already used). Best option is to choose 16.
>   Add 12 * 16 to sum, so sum is now 246.
>   For last number from second
>   array - 9 - you can choose only 10.Add 9 * 10 to sum, so sum is now
>   336.

I had few ideas, but every one of them was wrong. For example I tried to sort both arrays and then biggest number in second array multiply with biggest possible number in  first array (because 1. number in second array can choose only from 1.-3. position in first array, second number can choose only from 1.-4. etc.), but this isn't right. Also I have some more solutions, but too hard for me to explain them, because I don't know how to express it in English(But I could post a code and try to explain it) , and they also aren't right.
EDIT: I have found some algorithms that may be solution for my problem. First is [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm), second is [Auction Algorithm](https://agtb.wordpress.com/2009/07/13/auction-algorithm-for-bipartite-matching/). This is my first contact with linear programming... I understand how Hungarian algorithm works, but I can't implement it. In Auction algorithm I'm not even sure how it works. Also, I don't know if they are fast enough. Hungarian algorithm's time complexity is O(n^3) and I in my case n <= 500, so for maximum n it might last too long. Also in [Assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) every "worker" can do every "job", but in my case it isn't true.
It maybe can be [Max flow problem](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-bipartite-matching/),but I'm not so sure about this, because I need a perfect matching - it means that every vertex is matched - and I don't know if it is guaranteed by this algorithm.

Comment: Are you allowed to do it with brute force?

Comment: No, I can't do it using brute force

Comment: Why no brute-force? Homework/Theoretical question? You want so solve "real problems" (how big)?

Comment: It is task from webpage which has a test entries and a time limit, that's why no brute-force. I do tasks from this page to improve my skills.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as for me it's not clearly why for first number from the second array we should use only three first items from the first array, and for each other numbers from the second array we use anyone numbers from the first array.

However, we can represent this two arrays as a bipartite graph, where each number from the second array connect to (each?*) numbers from the first array. In this graph each edge (u,v) has a weight which equal to multiplication of the two numbers from arrays (u*v).
And for given graph you should resolve [max flow problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem).

* if I understand the problem correctly, you should connect first number from the 2nd array with first 3 numbers from the 1st array, and each other number from 2nd array with each numbers from the 1st array.

Comment: You should connect every number from the 2nd array with only first 3 numbers from the 1st array, which aren't used. So for every number in second array you have only 3 options.

Comment: @JozefBugoš, oh, I understood. So, you could create a graph, where 1st number from 2nd array will be connected with first 3 numbers from the first one; second number from second array should be connected with first 4 items from the first array; third number with first 5 numbers from the first array and so one... And for this graph you could implement (or just use) max-flow algo.

Comment: I was thinking about this too, but I had problem with using maximum flow in bipartite graph. But just a few moments ago I've found this: [Maximum Bipartite Matching](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-bipartite-matching/) and this [matching](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ckingsf/bioinfo-lectures/matching.pdf). I haven't read it very carefully yet, but I think this may be my solution, right?

Comment: But now as I've read both articles I'm not sure, because I need a perfect matching - it means that every vertex is matched. But I have found also this and it seems exactly like my problem: [Assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem)

Comment: After a quick glance, i don't think that matching-problems or assignment problems (hungarian algorithm) will help you. It looks like an NP-complete problem to me. Maybe i will have some time to think more about it. The reason for this "hardness" in my opinion is the "only first three" rule. This rule adds some dependencies which result in order-dependent effects. If this problem is as hard as i think: branch-and-bound based algorithms/integer programming or constraint-programming are natural choices for tackling this problem!

Answer (score 0):

> Continue doing this until every number is used. Write the biggest possible sum of these multiples

This looks like a discrete and combinatorial optimization problem. This first algorithm which came to my mind for solving this is by using **[Branch and Bound](http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/course/cis680/cis680Ch20.html)** algorithm.

It allows back tracking and you can implement it with recursion.

Comment: I'll have look at it.

Comment: @JozefBugoš It may take you sometime to digest how it works, but I am pretty sure it can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a Mixed-Integer Programming approach in [Julia](http://julialang.org/) using [JuMP](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/JuMP.jl). It works for your example and the general concept should work, but may need more testing!

It should be quite readable even if you are not familiar with julia. Keep in mind, that indexing starts with 1 (like in Matlab) instead of 0 (like in C, Java, ...)

The basic idea is the following (read the comments to understand more): define a binary variable X with dimension (N,N): if X[a,b] == 1 -> A[b] was chosen in step a.

The hardest part to understand is the bigM-Formulation which is just a *different formulation* of the logic explained in the comments. It's sole purpose is *linearizing*!

```
using JuMP

N = 4
A = [16 6 2 10]
B = [3 8 12 9]

# MODEL
m = Model()

# VARS
@defVar(m, x[1:N, 1:N], Bin)  # N steps, N vars/indices // binary

# CONSTRAINTS
# (1) exactly one var chosen in each step
for s = 1:N 
    @addConstraint(m, sum(x[s,:]) == 1)
end

# (2) each var is chosen exactly once
for v = 1:N 
    @addConstraint(m, sum(x[:,v]) == 1) 
end 

# (3) if var v chosen in step s -> are enough predecessors already taken away -> is in positions 1:3?
for s = 1:N 
    for v = 1:N 
        needed_pops_before = v - 3
        if needed_pops_before > 0
            # bigM formulation:
            # formula: (x[s,v] == 1) -> sum of predecessors taken away until now >= needed_pops
            #   use deMorgan-law -> !(x[s,v] == 1) -> sum >= needed_pops    
            #   formulate with bigM = N because needed_pops limited by N-3
            @addConstraint(m, N * (1-x[s,v])  + sum{x[ss,jj], ss=1:s-1, jj=1:v-1} >= needed_pops_before)
        end 
    end 
end

# OBJECTIVE
@setObjective(m, Max, sum{B[s] * A[v] * x[s,v], s=1:N, v=1:N})

# SOLVE
status = solve(m)

# OUTPUT
println("Objective is: ", getObjectiveValue(m))
println("Solution: ")
for s = 1:N 
    for v = 1:N 
        if getValue(x[s,v]) > 0.00001
            print(A[v], " ")
        end 
    end
end
```

Output:

```
Objective is: 336.0
Solution:
2 6 16 10
```